# LibreOffice Base Read read input, display from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, libreoffice-base

So basically I have 2 tables called Product and Category. The Product has the following fields :

```
ID integer, Name varchar(50), Notes varchar(200), Category integer
```

The Category has the following fields :

```
ID integer, Name varchar(50)
```

I have to create a form now which reads from a textbox an input string (the name of the product) and displays if this Name has been found the other content in a few textboxes. I don't know how to do it!

The second problem is, it has to read the category from Product, take it's value and find it in the Category's table and get the string. This string has to be displayed on the form.

How do I do it with LibreOffice Base?!

Comment: I think you need a basic tutorial on LO Base forms, first and foremost. Here's a good one : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-create-a-database-form-in-libreoffice-base-design-view/

Comment: I do know how to create a form, create some textboxes etc. I just don't know how to display, search etc.